# Console.Write(new string('* ', n) Too many characters in character literal

Tags: c#

So I want this to work like so

```
Console.WriteLine(new string('* ', 3);

Output:
* * *
```

But instead it just says "Too many characters in character literal" and I have to do it this way instead:

```
for (int i =0; i < 3; i ++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
         {
             Console.Write("*");
             Console.Write(" ");
         }
```

Can anyone tell me how I can fix the first code?

Comment: Do you need the last space after the last star?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char` name refers to character, and in `'* '` code there are two characters: `'*'` and `' '` (whitespace). Therefore, it should be a string, characters and strings differ by type of quotes: `'` vs `"`. Unfortunately, there is no overload of `string` constructor to accept another string and multiplier. So you need to reproduce same logic with different approach. One of them is below

```
var newStr = string.Join(string.Empty, Enumerable.Repeat("* ", 3));
```